# Tesla's theory of gravity

Tags: gravity, history

I was reading up on Tesla's Wikipedia page last night, and I came across this:

> When he was 81, Tesla stated he had
>   completed a "dynamic theory of
>   gravity". He stated that it was
>   "worked out in all details" and that
>   he hoped to soon give it to the
>   world. [75] The theory was never
>   published.

I was wondering, has this theory ever been found? [Here's a link to the Wikipedia article on Tesla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikola_Tesla#Field_theories)

Comment: I doubt it exists and even if it does, it would probably be complete crackpottery. If you'll read the reference [75] you'll find that Tesla is saying that the theory of curved space-time is impossible because of his observation that the curved space-time would have to straighten itself and because of some other philosophical blabbering. Needless to say, this is a complete rubbish and I don't think it's worth pursuing his theories any further.

Comment: I completely agree with Marek's comment.

Comment: Indeed. Alongside the certain amount of good physics Tesla did, there was somewhat more complete rubbish!

Comment: Oh wow, I just read that reference and he is pretty ridiculous in it :S Still, it may be...interesting... to see what his theory was

Comment: Basically, Tesla was against Special Relativity (and GR obviously). He had his version of non-relativistic electromagnetism. See Tesla waves for example.

Comment: "has this theory ever been found" is a question about filing and not a question that falls into the topics listed in the FAQ

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I wouldn't call it off topic, though it is indeed eliciting discussion. I have protected it for now,  I may close it as NC later if needed.

Answer (score 13):

Tesla was an engineering giant but it is true that in most cases, he was just a crackpot when it came to theoretical physics. This "theory of gravity" is one of the major ones.

It wasn't really connected with gravity - the attraction of objects to the Earth etc. with a universal acceleration - by anything else than a wishful thinking. As expected for the practical guy, most of the support for his unusual claims came from experiments, and it was the electromagnetic experiments.

Tesla claimed that the vacuum was filled with a new kind of the aether, a rarified gas that he also called the Akasha. This name is relatively important in his theory so you can get some idea about the character of the theory. The Akasha was extremely elastic.

Some spectacular experiments with some light emitted by either dielectric materials or conductors were made to support the claims, although they didn't have anything to do with the claims about the unifying theory. And at the end, it was found out that the experiments analyzed solidified air rather than any mysterious matter that could be filling the vacuum.

So the theory was a complete nonsense. Tesla couldn't really distinguish the fundamental phenomena from the highly derived, environment-dependent ones.

Comment: As an aside 'Akasha' is the sanskrit word for ether/cosmos/sky in general ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akasha

Comment: One has to remember that Newton was an alchemist who spent a lot of time on astrology. Its completely normal for people with good ideas to also have not so good ones!

Comment: Dear @TomAndersen, the difference is that alchemy was the state-of-the-art chemistry of Newton's times, and astrology was a broader science about the implications of celestial bodies – a science that was later made obsolete mostly by insights that followed from Newton's works. On the other hand, Tesla's musings about gravity and many other things were not state-of-the-art descriptions of anything. They were wrong even relatively to the ideas of his time.

Comment: also one has to remember that most of the crackpottery of Tesla popped up as he started to get old. The science before then was pretty solid

Answer (score 7):

It was said at the time (1930's) that only 10 people understood General Relativity. Tesla was clearly **not** one of them! :-)

- [Faster than light](http://www.tesla.hu/tesla/articles/19311100/page_1.gif) article
- [Bonkers article](http://www.tesla.hu/tesla/articles/19311100/index.htm) in which he still asserts that the aether exists

etc.

So, no, the theory has never been released - but if it was consistent with the various beliefs held by Tesla at the time, it must have been completely wrong.

Comment: Here's the patent where he claims a velocity of 1.6c: http://www.google.com/patents?id=oSo_AAAAEBAJ&zoom=4&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22four%20hundred%22&f=false

Comment: Einstein also believed in an ether. http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Extras/Einstein_ether.html

Comment: if you think about it the difference between relativity and an aether theory is pretty slim

Comment: @Skyler a theory which assumes an aether after it's been experimentally disproven is very different: it's experimentally wrong. :-)

Comment: I agree that it's been disproven, but the apparent difference between these two was pretty blurry, historically speaking. Instead of the ether being something in space it became an aspect of space.